How do Mini-PCI-Express Cards signal that they connect via USB 3.0
The Mini PCI express standard (the connector that is often used in Notebooks for 4G/5G modem cards) allows the card to chose whether it connects electrically via USB oder uses the PCIe lane. Since the standard update in 2014, the connector can also offer USB SuperSpeed. The SSTX and SSRX lanes are on the same pins as the PCIe lanes would be. If I am informed correctly, the M.2 cards handle this differently and have separate pins for USB and the PCIe lanes. How does the mPCIe card tell it's host that it wants to use USB 3.0 including the SS lanes and not connect the PCIe lane? How is this switching implemented on the host?
Ref:

https://pcisig.com/add-usb-30-mini-card
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102444/1-0/Target-interface-connectors/Mini-PCIe-Connector

